# ruby new instance of array ,hash

Tags: ruby

Sorry if this question is so dummy

I would like to know what is the difference of

```
a = Array.new  and a = []
b = Hash.new   and b = {}
```

WHat is the preferred way to get new instance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's preferred to use `[]` and `{}` because you are able to redefine the `initialize` methods of `Array` and `Hash` so hence it can be unreliable.

Example:

```
class Array
  def initialize
    # cause chaos
  end
end
```

`[]` and `{}` is also shorter :)

An extended example of the issue would be this:

```
class Array
  def initialize
    self << 1
  end
end

Array.new 
# => [1]

[] 
# => []
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` and `{}` have been created spesially to make your life better =) 
No reasons you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a regular empty literal, there is no difference between the two. `[]` and `{}` are more conventional.

The actual difference comes when you need to do something fancier. Literals let you specify the contents of the array or hash, while the `new` method lets you do things like make an array with an arbitrary number of the same object, or a hash whose default value is something other than nil.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-c-new) can be used in creating an Array in 3 different ways:

Verbatim from ruby-doc website:

new(size=0, obj=nil)
    new(array)
    new(size) {|index| block }
    Returns a new array.

```
In the first form, if no arguments are sent, the new array will be empty. When a size and an optional obj are sent, an array is created with size copies of obj. Take notice that all elements will reference the same object obj.

The second form creates a copy of the array passed as a parameter (the array is generated by calling #to_ary on the parameter).

first_array = ["Matz", "Guido"]

second_array = Array.new(first_array) #=> ["Matz", "Guido"]

first_array.equal? second_array       #=> false
In the last form, an array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element’s index to the given block and storing the return value.

Array.new(3){ |index| index ** 2 }
# => [0, 1, 4]
Common gotchas¶ ↑

When sending the second parameter, the same object will be used as the value for all the array elements:

a = Array.new(2, Hash.new)
# => [{}, {}]

a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {"cat"=>"feline"}]

a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
a # => [{"cat"=>"Felix"}, {"cat"=>"Felix"}]
Since all the Array elements store the same hash, changes to one of them will affect them all.

If multiple copies are what you want, you should use the block version which uses the result of that block each time an element of the array needs to be initialized:

a = Array.new(2) { Hash.new }
a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {}]
```

while `[]` creates an empty array for you

the above is similar for [Hash.new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) and `{}`